# When trying to use v-slot:append-inner to customize dropdown icon for v-combobox creates two dropdown icon in vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I want to call different function when dropdown icon inside v-combobox is clicked. So when i try to implement that function by modifying v-slot:append-inner and adding function, there is two dropdown icon. Is my approach wrong, if it is how should I go about solving this. My template code

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-combobox
      v-model="userInput"
      :items="propItems"
      dense
      item-text="name"
      item-value="name"
      multiple
      return-object
    >
      <template v-slot:append-inner>
        <v-icon @click="yourFunction">mdi-menu-down</v-icon>
      </template>
    </v-combobox>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  const propItems = ref(['Gaming', 'Programming', 'Vue', 'Vuetify'])
  const selectedItems = ref([])
  const userInput = ref('')
  const isDropOpen = ref(false)

  const yourFunction = () => {
    alert('here')
  }
</script>
```

[Vuetify playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNplUctuwjAQ/JWVLwaJgPpSJQSolapWnNpTL8DBJBvq1i/5QUGIf++GJATUU+yZ2cnOeHFgweejZ+eG24RszCYRtVMi4mxpACbbLLcmCmnQQ6mSLE5wQ+i1XdtdDQBsM20LVNMlSwH93LgUl6wlx5J8A3HOWzevzh1XoAnYXipdFnEXSWuExk52YrZCJfxH6aSidOps4jEmbzK7/sY81mCzN23eBqSFg7JxLJxD0+ZqsklKDU+5kvkP/Wxvk39NJo/SmiWb6UJmGk3KCvtrJqNa3fmPrhqsgK6rutQT0LRKyNUEXUPupYsQKIQ7DUjtrI9woFwlHKH0VgOn5+KVHIC8QoRzsTCtdL0FfxNamg0fAP/wduOFbq+fNFp/oiz3fNXvXAIqqgyLK6dLwfltG5LzC1KGF9rinfps2FKogCToJJddkqjXh+kMDnVTQqGPPf6FHmvXY1VOXQcVwY4Ddje8H97esOrwMHxkqz93JeSJ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that's what you want.
Set prop "menu-icon" as empty so the default icon is removed

```
 menu-icon=""
```

Also added a @mousedown.stop.prevent to stop the default dropdown behavior when clicking the icon. If you just wanted to remove the icon skip this part.

```
<v-icon @mousedown.stop.prevent @click="yourFunction">mdi-menu-down</v-icon>
```

[Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: That is how I solved also. But it seems little hackey, I think there should be better way out there.